# How do I resolve forbidden access problem in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I've been trying to implement the following shopping cart website on xampp. The link for the page is : http://www.w3programmers.com/build-a-shopping-cart-with-php-part-1/

However when I try running my login page I get the following error:-

Here's the tab that opens when I try to login:

[image]

Here's the login code :-

```
<?php
session_start();

require("config.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN']) == TRUE) {
header("Location:".$config_basedir);    
}

if($_POST['submit'])
{
$loginsql = "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE username = '" . $_POST['userBox']. "' AND password = '" . $_POST['passBox'] . "'";
$loginres = mysql_query($loginsql);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($loginres);
if($numrows == 1)
{
$loginrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($loginres);
session_register("SESS_LOGGEDIN");
session_register("SESS_USERNAME");
session_register("SESS_USERID");
$_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN'] = 1;
$_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] = $loginrow['username'];
$_SESSION['SESS_USERID'] = $loginrow['id'];
$ordersql = "SELECT id FROM rides WHERE customer_id = " . $_SESSION['SESS_USERID'] . " AND status < 2"; 
$orderres = mysql_query($ordersql); 
$orderrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($orderres); 
session_register("SESS_ORDERNUM"); $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] = $orderrow['id'];
 header("Location:".$config_basedir);
}
else {
header("Location:http://" .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . "?error=1");
}
}
else {
require("header.php");
?>
<h1>Customer Login</h1>

Please enter your username and password to log into the websites. If you do not have an account, you can get one for free by <a href="register.php">registering</a>.

<?php
if(isset($_GET['error'])) {
echo "<strong>Incorrect username/password</strong>";
}
?>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?><br />" method="POST">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Username</td>
<td><input type="textbox" name="userBox" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td><input type="password" name="passBox" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>

<?php
}
require("footer.php");
?>
```

And here's the header code:-

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_CHANGEID'])==TRUE){
        session_unset();
        session_regenerate_id();
    }
    require("config.php");

    $db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);

    mysql_select_db($dbdatabase, $db);
?>


        <head>
            <title><?php echo $config_sitename; ?></title>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheet.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="header">
                <h1><?php echo $config_sitename; ?></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <a href="<?php echo $congif_basedir; ?>">Home</a>
                <a href="<?php echo $congif_basedir; ?>">View Rides</a>
            </div>  
            <div id="container">
                <div id="bar">
                    <?php
                        require("bar.php");
                        echo "<hr>";

                        if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN'])==True){
                            echo "Logged in as <strong>".$_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']."</strong>[<a href='".$congif_basedir."logout.php'>logout</a>]";
                        }else{
                            echo "<a href='".$config_basedir."login.php'>Login</a>";    
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>  

            <div id="main">
```

I suspect it's something to do with the header function, though I'm not really sure.

Comment: That looks like Chrome. Can you try using another browser please

Comment: Also you **really reallllyyyyy** should look for a better **newer** tutorial. Specifically one that **does not use the old and now removed `mysql_` database access API**

Comment: PS: This message from Apache is nothing to do with your code. Apache has not let you IN so the code has not even been looked for by Apache yet

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried it in firefox but it produced the same result , I even tried changing the xampp permissions in httpd-xampp .

Answer (score 0):

May I ask you to put here code from config.php? Or at least tell what value of $config_basedir?

**Updated**: `$config_basedir` should be URL in this format: `http://localhost/ . 'some folders' . 'file name with extension'`, for example, like this: `http://localhost/sites/shop/index.php`.

If a file or folder of the file is located in the same or child directory your URL can be just: file `'file_name` or `folder/file_name`. For example just `index.php` or `folder/folder/index.php`.

An extension like `.php | .html`may not be mandatory depending on your server settings. That is, you can indicate the URL like this: `folder/index` or `index`; 'index' - is a file name in this case.